# Common Lisp: Exported Function Undefined

Tags: makefile, package, common-lisp, sbcl

I have created an executable a few times with the asdf system. I know there are other ways to do this but I want to figure out why this is not working this time.

I have a rock-paper-scissor game.

The lisp file:

```lisp
(defun main ()
  (let* ((x (y-or-n-p (format t "Is there two players? [Y/N]"))))
    (if (equal x t)
    (rps-game2)
    (rps-game))))

... other stuff
```

The package.lisp:

```lisp
(defpackage #:rps
      (:use #:cl)
      (:export main))
```

The rps.asd

```lisp
(asdf:defsystem #:rps
       :components ((:file "package")
                    (:file "rps"))
        :build-operation "program-op"
        :build-pathname "launch"
        :entry-point "rps:main")
```

The makefile:

```bash
build:
    sbcl \
     --eval '(load "rps.asd")' \
    --eval '(ql:quickload "rps")' \
     --eval '(asdf:make :rps)' \
     --eval '(quit)'
```

The error message:

`The function rps:main is an undefined`

I followed the exact same process as a previous package I created. For some reason, main is unrecognised this time. Why?

Comment: Is there a call to `(in-package "RPS")` in the lisp file, before the function `main` is actually defined ? Otherwise, you're actually defining `cl:main`, not `rfs:main`

Comment: The default is not CL, but maybe CL-USER ... The Common Lisp package has no MAIN symbol.

Comment: main is a function I defined in my rps.lisp @RainerJoswig

Comment: @Numbra I believe there is a chicken and egg happening... if I add `(in-package "rps")` to my `rps.lisp`, then when I (ql:quickload "rps"), I get the error that "RPS" is not a package.

Comment: @Vinn Either you use a symbol: `(in-package #:rps)` or the name of that symbol: `(in-package "RPS")` - the latter with capital letters, because the reader "upcases symbol names" by default (things are slightly more complicated, but that is a good-enough approximation here).
Another problem could indeed be that the package in not yet defined when you 'move' into it, and then it is compilation order problem.

Comment: Interesting. That is an easy detail to miss. Thank you.

Comment: I am surprised to see `(:export main)` and not `'main` or `#'main`.

Comment: mmm, I do not know. Why does `(:export main)` work? My executable creates successfully and the main function is launched.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following issues:

1. In my `rps.asd` I added `serial t`. I believe this tells lisp to compile the files in order. Therefore the package gets compiled first, then the rps file.
2. I added `(in-package #:rps)` to the rps.lisp file. (thanks @Numbra)